# Problem with UPDATE Operation On Entity Framework 4 (Pure POCOs)

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc-2, entity-framework-4, poco, objectstatemanager

I have an Entity Framework 4.0 model implemented with pure POCO's (no code generation, no self-tracking entities, just plain old CLR objects).

Now, here is some code i have in my UI to perform an **UPDATE:**

```
[HttpPost]
public ActionResult UpdatePerson(Person person)
{
    repository.Attach(person);
    unitOfWork.Commit();
}
```

Essentially, i have an Action Method which accepts a strongly-typed Person object, and i need to UPDATE this entity.

Doesn't error, but also doesn't persist the changes to the DB either. :(

When i inspect the **EntityState** during the "Commit" of my Unit of Work:

```
var entities = ObjectStateManager.GetObjectStateEntries(EntityState.Added | EntityState.Deleted | EntityState.Modified | EntityState.Unchanged);
```

I see my entity, with **EntityState.Unchanged**.

So that explains why it has not been persisted. My Find,Add,Delete operations are working fine (persisting correctly). But UPDATE doesn't seem to work.

I've found some threads saying i need to *manually* set the object state:

```
ctx.ObjectStateManager.ChangeObjectState(person, EntityState.Modified);
```

Is that correct? Where would i put this logic? Expose as an operation on my Unit of Work?

Obviously the issue is i have **no change tracking** whatsoever, due to the use of Pure POCO's (no EntityObject derivation, no INotifyPropertyChanging implementation).

But i haven't found an issue with it until now.

What am i doing wrong?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Well, since you don't have any change tracking, etc., there should be a way for EF to determine what to do with the attached entity when `SaveChanges()` is called. By default, the EntityState is Unchanged, so if you want to Update, you have to manually set the state.

Another way would be to query for the `Person` with this Id, rewrite the properties with the data you fetch from the controller, and call `SaveChanges()`. This is a safer way actually, since you can guard yourself from a situation where the Person gets deleted while the user is editing the webform; but this obviously requires an extra roundtrip to the DB, which is often less desirable.

In any case, I would have a repository `Update()` method (more specific than `Attach`), that would actually attach the entity and change the `EntityState` to `Modified`. And you still have relatively clean code in your Action:

```
public ActionResult UpdatePerson(Person person)
{
    repository.Update(person);
    unitOfWork.Commit();
}
```

Comment: Yeah, i don't really want to do an extra round trip. So we have to manually set the EntityState (as i predicted). Cool, thanks. Also - i was thinking - is there a way the "Update" method can be smart enough to figure out if it's an UPDATE or an INSERT? (ie check the PersonId, if its > 0, it's an UPDATE, else an INSERT?) or is that too crazy/scary. Would be nice if the one method could handle both scenarios. Possible?

Comment: As far as I understand, you are talking about the `Update()` method you are to create, so you can make it as smart as you would like ;) E.g. Attach entity, then do the check `if (Person.Id == 0) { /* change state to Added */ } else { /* Change state to Modified */ }`. I am not sure it's a great idea, though. Having separate methods for inserting and updating is generally more readable. Why would you want to merge them into one?

Comment: Because i'm using MVC, and the operation of adding/modifying a Person entity is the same (HTTP POST, pass through strongly typed object). So i have no way of knowing if it's an add or update (of course, i could pass through an extra flag). I agree though, i'll seperate them out, might have to pass through hidden field in HTTP POST stating it's an add/update. Thanks